# How to update a OleDb (access) database in c# using a data grid view

Tags: c#, oledb

I have a method that queries an oledb database and gives the result to a data grid view. Now I want to update the database using the same data grid view. when I change the results in the data grid view and click the update button,It should be updated in the database. I searched for the codes for it and the codes which I found are not working. My view method and the update method are below.Please help me with this update code.

```
private void btnViewSaleView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String sql = "select * from business where billNumber=(?)";
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtViewSaleBillNumber.Text);
        String textViewSaleStringTemp;
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader res = com.ExecuteReader();
       if (res.Read())
        {
            textViewSaleStringTemp = res["salesRepNumber"].ToString();
            txtViewSaleSalesRepNumber.Text = textViewSaleStringTemp;
            textViewSaleStringTemp = res["Customer"].ToString();
            txtViewSaleCustomer.Text = textViewSaleStringTemp;
            textViewSaleStringTemp = res["cashReceived"].ToString();
            txtViewSaleCashReceived.Text = textViewSaleStringTemp;
            textViewSaleStringTemp = res["paymentCompleteDate"].ToString();
            txtViewSalePaymentCompletedDate.Text = textViewSaleStringTemp;
          }
       OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter();
       String sqlDGV = "select * from BillItem where billNumber=(?)";
       OleDbCommand comDGV= new OleDbCommand(sqlDGV, connection);
       ada.SelectCommand = comDGV;
       comDGV.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtViewSaleBillNumber.Text);
       DataTable t = new DataTable();
       ada.Fill(t);
       DGVViewSale.DataSource = t;
       connection.Close();

    } 
 private void btnViewSaleUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommandBuilder cmb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(ada);
        ada.Update(t);
 //but this command doesn't recognize data adapter and the data table

    }
```

Comment: I presume this is because you are delcaring your datatable and dattaadapter in btnViewSaleView_Click so it is out of scope when called in btnViewSaleUpdate_Click
I would create a method named SaveData that takes a Datatable and and a OleDbDataAdapter and then move the logic from btnViewSaleUpdate_Click into this method, then in btnViewSaleUpdate_Click you can call SaveData(t, ada);

Comment: You should [learn about scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx).